# How to create an Array UIImage in Swift

Tags: swift, uiimage

This my code

```
var changePhoto = [UIImage]()
let photoPng = UIImage(named: "1.png")
let photoJpg = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")

changePhoto += photoPng
changePhoto += photoJpg
```

but error "expected declaration"

Please help me! What's wrong?

Comment: Could you add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: error is expected declaration. No explain any more. ^^

Comment: @rintaro Thanks lot. I think that exactly problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `append` method to add new objects to your array:

```
changePhoto.append(photoPng)
changePhoto.append(photoJpg)
```

Also, you only can have functionality inside of methods. So try to call it inside a method. for example if you use a Viewcontroller in your `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: I already use that code. But it's not done. Same error. I'm using Xcode 6.3 beta 4. But in my opinion it's not issue.

Comment: Try  changePhoto.append(photoPng!)

Comment: @MinhThắngTrương Check my update. Maybe you call it outside of a function. That's not allowed. You can only use functionality inside a method.

Comment: @Christian! Thanks! that's exactly excuse.

Comment: Glad it worked. If you accept the answer, other people can find it easier.